# Plotting mediation in time to event data

Tags: plot, cox-regression, longitudinal, pbmplus

Thanks in advance for any help. I basically have a mediation analysis of time-to-event data (time to death) in MPlus which has run perfectly etc. I am trying to work out ways that i could plot this in rstudio so I can modify its appearance etc. In my mind it would be great to have the typical cox regression plot with events across years, but then have bands to show the impact of either one or two mediators (or multiple mediators). I just dont know how to do this or plot the impact of a mediator across time to an event. My r knowledge is very limited to checking assumptions etc for cox regression. I havent worked out to run the mediation in time to event in r just yet so i stick to the running it in mplus as i know it is correct. I have the following results from mplus, direct (hazard ratio), indirect estimate 1 (mediator 1), total effect 1 (mediator plus direct 1), indirect estimate 2 (mediator 2), total effect 2 (mediator 2 put direct), and both indirect mediators together. Any advice on what i could do to plot this type of information really nicely? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.